# querySelectorAll Regex with variable

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match an element with an attrib string with two variables row, site. The attribute is "data-test". The format is

data-test = "siteQtySOMETEXTrow=xxSOMETEXTsite=yySOMETEXT

I think the easiest way is with regex, using new RegExp

I've got 2 issues 1) constructing the regex and 2) passing the regex into querySelectorAll

```
var mystr = "\\b" + "siteQty" + "\\b.*\\brow=" + myrow + "\\b.*\\site=" + mysite + "\\b";
 console.log("mystr = "+mystr);
//=>  mystr = \bsiteQty\b.*\brow=10\b.*\site=1\b

 var myreg = new RegExp("'" + '[data-test^='+ '"' + mystr + '"' + "]" + "'");
 console.log("myreg after = "+myreg);
//=>  myreg after = /'[data-test^="\bsiteQty\b.*\brow=10\b.*\site=1\b"]'/

 var mycells = document.querySelectorAll(myreg);
  console.log("I found "+mycells.length+" of "+ myrow + "," + mysite + "data-test");  
//=> nothing
```

I think I've got most of the way to the solution, but it's not working.

Is it the regex ? or the passing of the regex into the query ? or something else ?

Comment: Adding some sample DOM elements which you'd like to locate would be helpful to verify that a proposed solution actually works.

Comment: you do realize you can have as many `data-` attributes as you need - right? Seems to be quite easy then `if( first data- && second data- && third)` eetc.

Comment: `querySelectorAll` doesn't accept a regex as an argument at all. It will be implicitly stringifyied.

Comment: `data-` definition is not under my control unfortunately

Comment: @Quentin, interesting..what does
`var sqs=document.querySelectorAll('[colid^="sq"]')`
do then ? I thought this was regex for starts with - this works for colid elements.

Comment: @Col.in — It's a [selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/) (hence the name of the function)

Comment: @ggorlen I can't post actual elements, but I did post an outline format
`data-test = "siteQtySOMETEXTrow=xxSOMETEXTsite=yySOMETEXT`

Comment: @Quentin, I'm missing something then. I'm bootstrapping myself in javascript on web pages. Is what I want even possible ?

Comment: Instead of writing the ultimate selector(which is not regex as @Quentin already pointed out) the way to go is to just match all elements with the data attribute and filtering the result set. It's less error prone, simpler to extend / maintain and more concise.

Comment: @LJᛃ I was trying to avoid getting all the elements since there could be 1000's of them. Concerned that this would take too long and slow the page. Any other options ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that we wish to capture three variables from our string, for which we'd be simply using an expression with three groups, as simple as:

```
^siteQty(.+?)row=(.+?)site=(.*)$
```

and we would script the rest of our problem.

We can likely replace these groups `(.+?)` and include additional boundaries, if necessary.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/Nc4vGk/1/)

#### Example

```js
const regex = /siteQty(.+?)row=(.+?)site=(.*)/gm;
const str = `siteQtySOMETEXTrow=xxSOMETEXTsite=yySOMETEXT

`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### Boolean match

```js
console.log(/^siteQty(.+?)row=(.+?)site=(.*)$/.test('siteQtySOMETEXTrow=xxSOMETEXTsite=yySOMETEXT'));
```

For capturing lower and uppercases in our value inputs, we can for instance use these expression:

```
^siteQty(.+?)row=(([a-z]+)([A-Z]+?))site=(([a-z]+)([A-Z]+))$
^siteQty(.+?)row=(([a-z]+)([A-Z]+))site=(([a-z]+)([A-Z]+))$
```

```js
const regex = /^siteQty(.+?)row=(([a-z]+)([A-Z]+?))site=(([a-z]+)([A-Z]+))$/gm;
const str = `siteQtySOMETEXTrow=xxSOMETEXTsite=yySOMETEXT
 siteQtySOMETEXTrow=xxSOMETEXTsite=yySOMETEXT
iteQtySOMETEXTrow=xxSOMETEXTsite=yySOMETEXT

`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/XihgaX/1)

Comment: wow. that's complete for the regex part. How can I use it as a selector ?

Comment: I think I got my selector answer above. For the regex how do I check for a simple match/no match ? Note that the string must start with "siteQty"

Comment: how do I pull the row value (xx) and site value (yy) from the string ?

Answer (score 0):

So eventually I set up strings with dummy placeholders for row and column, then used string functions to replace the dummy xx/yy values. Then put all three selectors into the `querySelectorAll`

```
      var myq_col = "[data-test*='site=xx']" ;
      var myq_col = myq_col.replace("xx",window.myred_col);
      var myq_row = "[data-test*='row=xx']" ;
      var myq_row = myq_row.replace("xx",window.myred_row);
      var myq_site = "[data-test^='siteQty']" ;
      console.log(" removing red @ ",myq_col + "|" + myq_row);

            var myadd= document.querySelectorAll(myq_site+myq_col+myq_row);
```